# Is there a way in Debezium to stop data serialization? Trying to get values from source as it is

Tags: debezium

I have seen many posts on StackOverflow where people are trying to capture the data from source RDBMS and are using Debezium for the same. I am working with SQL Server. However since the DECIMAL and TIMESTAMP values are encoded by default, it becomes an overhead to decode those values into its original form.
I was looking to avoid this extra decoding step but to no avail. Can anyone please tell me how to import data via Debezium as it is i.e. without serializing it.

I saw some youtube videos where DECIMAL values were extracted in its original form.
FOR EX->  800.0 from SQL Server is obtained as 800.0 via Debezium and not as "ATiA" (encoded)
But i am not sure how to do this. Can anyone please help me with what configuration will be required for the same on Debezium. I am using Debezium Server for now. Can work with Debezium connectors as well if that's needed.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It may be a matter of **representation**  of timestamp and decimal values as opposed to *encoding*.
For timestamps, try using different values of `time.precision.mode` and for decimals, use `decimal.handling.mode`.
For MySQL, documentation is [here](https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/stable/connectors/mysql.html#mysql-property-decimal-handling-mode)